# how do i select a element within a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-cycle

i have a slideshow that is using the cycle plugin and for some reason i cant select or target the correct elements see the code below:

HTML

```
<div id="slider">

    <div id="slideshow">
        <ul>                    
        <li><img src="images/slider-one.png" height="380" width="960" alt="AquaPure Traveller" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider-one.png" height="380" width="960" alt="AquaPure Traveller" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider-one.png" height="380" width="960" alt="AquaPure Traveller" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider-one.png" height="380" width="960" alt="AquaPure Traveller" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider-one.png" height="380" width="960" alt="AquaPure Traveller" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- End Slideshow -->

    <div id="prev">PREVIOUS</div>
    <div id="next">NEXT</div>

</div> <!-- End Slider -->
```

and the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Document Ready
            $('#slideshow ul li').cycle({
        'fx': 'scrollHorz', 
        'timeout': 8000,
        'prev': '#prev',
        'next': '#next',
        'pause': true
    });

}); // End Document Ready
```

what am i missing is it something simple or is it an issue with the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the jQuery Cycle Plugin right?

As far as I know you have to select the container / parent of the items. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
   $('#slideshow ul').cycle({
        'fx': 'scrollHorz', 
        'timeout': 8000,
        'prev': '#prev',
        'next': '#next',
        'pause': true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the JavaScript so that the cycle is applied to the ul element not the individual li:-

```
$('#slideshow ul').cycle();
```